# How to copy a weekly worksheet with a specific column of data onto a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hopefully someone knows the answer...I am new to usng VBA on excel.

I am trying to create a Weekly Grocery budget for our Canteen Staff.
What i have been trying to do is to allow the user to create each weekly budget on a new worksheet.

What i have created so far is Table that includes a "Stock Start" and a "Stock End" column. What the Head of the Kitchen would like is for the "Stock End" column to move over to the "Stock Start" column when a new worksheet is created.

I thought the best way would be to allow the user to populate the worksheet with data and then on the click of a button it would create a new worksheet and copy the "stock end" column into the "stock Start" of the newly created worksheet.

I also wanted to set up a standardised naming convention, such a a "week beginning DD/MM/YY. But this proved too diffcult.

I have managed to find 2 separate pieces of code.

The first part duplicates the "Master" worksheet and allows the user to name the new worksheet themselves. This would be perfect, but it only relies on the "Master" worksheet. What I would prefer is for it to duplicate the Active worksheet.

The second part of the code which I have blocked of with '. will copy the data from Stock End (G4:G83) to the new sheet Stock Start (C4:C83).

But this code needs to know the names of the worksheets in which it is copying...

Becuase of this I can't get the 2 codes to work as one. I am at a lost...

Here is a copy of the spreadsheet in question on my google drive:

[Weekly Gorcery Budget](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Ahe17Osa3OQjlYY3FxcHd1YVE&authuser=0)

Kind Regards

T

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Worksheets("Master").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing

    'Worksheets(1).Range("G4:G83").Copy
    'Worksheets(2).Range("C4:C83").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Worksheets("Master")` and `Worksheets(1)` use `ActiveSheet`. Instead of using `Worksheets(2)` use `wks`.

Comment: Hi AnotherParker,

I have made the changes you suggested but it now comes with a debug error...

"Run-time error '91'
Object variable or With block variable not set

also i notice that it is trying to copy the data from the new Worksheet (G4:G83), but is unable to paste it into the required column (C4:C83)

in debug mode it highlights the last line
wks.Range("C4:C83").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Never mind,

I changed wks to ActiveSheet

and it seems to be working now.

carry out a few more test to make sure that it works through multiple sheets.

will this still work if i were to lock the cells that have the formula in...just so that the Kitchen Manager doesn't accidently delete the contents of the cell.

Comment: You can lock and unlock cells from VBA.

Comment: I got it all working now!

thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I used to get it all working..

Thank you AnotherParker for all your help!

T

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing

    ActiveSheet.Range("G4:G83").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4:C83").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


End Sub
```